# How to find row # using pandas and searching Spreadsheet Based Off User input?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to find out how to easily index the row number based on a search of the excel document.

```
from tkinter import *

import pandas as pd

database = pd.ExcelFile('C:/Code/CODETEST.xlsx').parse(sheet_name="Sheet1", skiprows=0, nrows=3)

excel_data_df = pd.read_excel('CODETEST.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1',)

##excel_data_dfRow = pd.read_excel('CODETEST.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', nrows=2)

print (excel_data_df)


##print(excel_data_df.columns.ravel())

##print(excel_data_df['Service Name'].tolist())

##Creating a service list for all services listed under "Serivce name" Column
My_Service_List = (excel_data_df['Service Name'].tolist())


My_Multicast_List = (excel_data_df['SRC DRAWING'].tolist())

column2 = excel_data_df.iloc[0, 3]
column3 = excel_data_df.iloc[:0, 4]

print (column2)
print(My_Service_List)

##print (excel_data_dfRow)


print(My_Multicast_List)

##print (database)



##Source1_Text = tk.StringVar()

root = Tk()

##Creating Entries
Group = Entry(root, width=50)
Group.grid(row=0, column=5)
Source = Entry(root, width=50)
Source.grid(row=1, column=5)
Service = Entry(root, width=50)
Service.grid(row=2, column=5)

Test = database

##if Test == Service.get():
  ##  print ("Yes")

Source1 = Button()

def Standard_flow():
    global Source1
    global My_Service_List
    global Test
    global column2
    Standard_window = Tk()
    ##Source1_Text = tk.StringVar()
    ##Source1_Text.set("Original Text")
    ##My_Service_ListTEST = Service.get()
    Source1 = Button(Standard_window, text=column2)
    Source1.grid(row=1, column=1)
    Source2 = Button(Standard_window, text=column3)
    Source2.grid(row=1, column=2)
    Source3 = Button(Standard_window, text='DCM')
    Source3.grid(row=1, column=3)

# Definining Buttons
def Okay():
    hello = "Searching " + Group.get()
    myLabel = Label(root, text=hello)
    myLabel.grid(row=0, column=6)


def Okay2():
    hello2 = "Searching " + Source.get()
    myLabel2 = Label(root, text=hello2)
    myLabel2.grid(row=1, column=6)


def Okay3():
    hello3 = "Searching " + Service.get()
    myLabel3 = Label(root, text=hello3)
    myLabel3.grid(row=2, column=6)
    if My_Service_List.__contains__(Service.get()):
        return Standard_flow()
    else:
        None


##Creating Buttons
myButton_Group = Button(root, text='Group Multicast IP', command=Okay)
myButton_Source = Button(root, text='Source IP', command=Okay2)
myButton_Service = Button(root, text='Service Name', command=Okay3)

##Displaying Buttons
myButton_Group.grid(row=0, column=1)
myButton_Source.grid(row=1, column=1)
myButton_Service.grid(row=2, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

I am using user input to check the excel document to see if the value exists in that specific column, but I also want to index the row # that the service if found is so I can print specific columns from that same row.

Would I need to do an if statement, along the lines of...

```
if My_Service_List.__contains__(Service.get()):
```

return or index the row # that contains the input

I need to use this row # later in code to print/show the user data from other columns for that same row.

Looked over documentation but having some issues pushing this forward, please disregard all the comments that make no sense in the code, I am trying things and commenting them out as I go.

I saw something about dt.loc to get the indexed row #

```
Searching = (excel_data_df.loc(Service.get()))

print (Searching)
```

But the problem is, "Service" is not defined when trying to run that.

*"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/206415779/Python/FINDIT/FINDIT START", line 37, in 
Searching = excel_data_df.loc(Service.get())
NameError: name 'Service' is not defined"*

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think my problem is I am looking at how to do this via import/export of the XLSX instead of looking at options to grab this from the data frame that was created? I'm going to go down that path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what got me what I needed. Answering in hopes to help someone down the road.

```
Searched_Multicast_Row_Location = excel_data_df_Sheet_1[excel_data_df_Sheet_1['Zixi Multicast'] == Group.get()].index
```

Creating the var "Searched_Multicast_Row_Location" to store the indexed row based off of "Group.get()" which comes from a user. "Zixi Multicast" is the column used for the search, I know the value is in that column so one the user inputs their search this var will query that column and find the row # of the value. I have another post that discusses setting this up to search multiple columns. If it is not clear, "excel_data_df_Sheet_1" is my df.